# Is it possible to make REST calls when the CSP cannot be changed from default-src: 'none'?

Tags: javascript, xss, content-security-policy

*This feels like a dumb question because it flies in the face of everything the Content Security Policy is supposed to do, I know.*

There is a webpage at `foo.baz.com` which needs data from `bar.baz.com` to run locally. Here is the function which gets that data and puts it in a cookie:

```
function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "https://bar.baz.com/endpoint");

    request.onload = () => {...put the results in a cookie...};

    request.send();
}
```

Unfortunately, the page on `foo.baz.com` has a CSP directive of `default-src: 'none'` and is owned by another team so I cannot change it. (This function is being run in the browser console.)

XMLHttpRequest, jQuery and fetch all produce this CSP error:

> Refused to connect to 'https://bar.baz.com/endpoint' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicit set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

**Is it at all possible to make an API call from one subdomain of `baz.com` to another when the CSP directive *cannot* be changed from `default-src: 'none'`?**

(Possibly by dynamically setting the `connect-src` directive, adding an access control header or using a library which can make requests in spite of the CSP?)

Comment: A bit tangential, I admit, but isn't the idea that if another team owns the application and is explicitly enforcing this header, that they don't want you using the service in this way?

Comment: Fair question, the other team provides tools to accomplish this task but unfortunately they no longer work. The tools are also so niche that they can't prioritize fixing them.

Comment: I understand this isn't the most helpful comment in the world, but this to me sounds like more of an administrative/collaborative issue than a technical one. If a requirement you're working on **critically requires** this functionality, this "other team" should generally be willing to make concessions in their headers in light of their own tools no longer working. At the very least, this other team should provide clear reasoning why they *won't* allow this. `default-src: 'none'` in this context is going to prohibit any communication your page might need to make with other pages/servers/etc.

Comment: You could write a proxy that runs on localhost that strips the CSP headers.

Comment: As far as *“a library which can make requests in spite of the CSP”*, there’s no such library and no possibility for any such library to work — because the blocking’s done by the browser and there’s no way from frontend code to trick the browser into ignoring the CSP restrictions. And as far as *“adding an access control header”*, if by that you mean a CORS response header, then no, any changes you make related to CORS won’t affect this. And as far as *“dynamically setting the connect-src directive”*, no you can’t — if you could work around CSP from frontend code, CSP would be pretty pointless.

Comment: One thing confusing about what’s described in the question is, you say the `foo.baz.com` site has this function in it which makes a request to `bar.baz.com`. Due to the CSP issue, that function won’t run for anybody who uses the `foo.baz.com` site. So the `foo.baz.com` site is broken. So, who put that function into the frontend code of the `foo.baz.com` site? The other team did? If so, why? Are they aware the site’s broken? Or did you put it in, and so you’re saying you have access to change the frontend code for `foo.baz.com` but you don’t have access to change the response headers? Or what?

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thank you for the definitive no. The function in question wasn't actually a part of `foo.baz.com`, rather it was being run from the browser console to trick `foo.baz.com` into loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this is not possible, something has to be redesigned.

What we did is remove the call to `bar.baz.com` and instead defined a placeholder cookie which satisfied the conditions for `foo.baz.com` to load. We then redirected all the REST calls leaving `foo.baz.com` to a proxy running locally. The proxy would make the call to `bar.baz.com` on startup and replace the placeholder cookie in outbound REST calls with the value from `baz.bar.com`. Then it forwards those requests to the appropriate host. The proxy we used is [express-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy) but there are a bunch like it.

Another option we almost got to work was writing a script which would start on `bar.baz.com` and make the call. Then it would store the results as a cookie or local variable and use `window.assign` to navigate to `foo.baz.com`. If anyone gets this to work I'd love to hear it.